# Is it possible to programmatically tell when the end of a webp loop is?

Tags: javascript, html, webp

I'm using webp as I need support for transparency in a video/gif format. My issue is I need the element to disappear once the animation has finished, and I'm not sure how exactly I can figure out when that has happened without hard coding it (which could lead to inconsistencies on slower hardware).

Before I was looping through a PNG sequence but the performance wasn't great, so I'd rather use this format if possible.

I'm using JavaScript and I currently just have it in an  tag as such:

```html
<img src="../../../assets/animations/anim.webp">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently this is not possible. Likely the best you can do is add a listener to the images load event and set a timer to the same length of the GIF animation. (Similar to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24385829/javascript-trigger-when-gif-animation-is-done))

```
<img onload="stopImage();" id="myImg" src="../../../assets/animations/anim.webp">
```

And in JS:

```
function stopImage()  {  
  setTimeout(
    () => document.getElementById('myImg').src = "../../../assets/staticImage.png"
    , 6700);   
}
```

Network load times do vary a lot, but the variance in play speed shouldn't be drastically different for short duration animations. If you need a fine level of control then you should control the animation manually with JS. Either as you were doing before with the PNG sequence, or as recommended in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16148815/5514077) with CSS sprite maps.